# How to convert hash into request url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, actiondispatch

I am having the hash with following keys

```
{:action=>'index', :controller=>'users', :search=>'John'}
```

I want to build a complete request url using this hash keys.
I tried using `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` class, but I couldn't able to get the url as expected.

I want to build the url like `http://localhost:3000/users?search=John`

How to get this request url?

Answer (score 2):

```
url_for(hash)
```

in your case:

```
url_for(:action=>'index', :controller=>'users', :search=>'John')
```

returns `/users?search=John` host_name will be added automatically.

If you explicitly want to add host_name you can pass host: key in your hash

Comment: I was in the process of providing this answer, based on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html, but `url_for` wasn't recognized when I typed that into the Rails console. After following the instructions in that doc about what to include, I was able to call the function, but it raised an error due to `request` not being defined. Any idea what was going on there?

Comment: I guess its not about "testing in console". Did you get it working inside the app?

Comment: I'm not the OP and I'm not questioning whether it works in the app. Just thought you might know why I was having trouble getting it to work in the console.

Comment: Actually I didnt try with console. 'll have a try